# How to execute command from local-exec provisioner with terraform plan?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have Terraform data block that fetches AMI details:

```
data "aws_ami" "current_ami" {
  owners = ["${var.aws_account_id}"]

  filter {
    name = "image-id"
    values = ["${data.terraform_remote_state.current_ami.outputs.ami_id}"]
   }
}
```

Then I am printing the my code details branch information of Git:

```
resource "null_resource" "build_info" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo 'Current Build: ${data.aws_ami.current_ami.tags.Branch}'"
  }
}
```

The above code runs command everytime when `terraform apply` is used but not with `terraform plan`. It just prints the `id` of `null_resource`.

I want the command from `local-exec` provisioner to execute everytime I run `terraform plan` to validate the AMI is built using proper branch.

Comment: Provisioner blocks will only execute on `apply`. Also, it appears that what you really want here is an `output` and not a `provisioner`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - I tried with output as well. It wont get executed with plan

Comment: this is pretty important need for me too because TF Apply is usually a protected ability in pipelines